# Unetbootin installation problem

Tags: debian, unetbootin

when I try to open Unetbootin after installation, I get that in small window :

```
    mlabelin found. Required for Arch Linux install mode.
Installation of the "mtools" package or the equivalent of your distribution
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> mlabelin found. Required for Arch Linux install mode.

> Installation of the "mtools" package or the equivalent of your distribution

Perhaps your are executing the binary file `./unetbootin-linux64-700.bin` which require `mtools`, it can be installed as follows:

```
sudo apt install mtools
```

An alternative way to install [unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/linux_download.html) on debian and debian derivatives:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gezakovacs/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unetbootin
```